# IconRenderer Warning in Xcode 11.2

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode11

I just created a new iOS Single View App and I try to build and run it. I had received the warning as below:

```
[Renderer] IconRenderer: HorizontalStretchPadding (18.000000, 18.000000) is larger than the image size (34.000000, 54.000000). Image will now use the center column of pixels to stretch.
```

This warning keeps showing multiple times.

Comment: I'm having this too. I'll ask if others have it.

Comment: As far I could tell, it related to the `MKMapView` but I still couldn't tell what trigger this warning.

Comment: Just check that do you have added an icon with size (34, 54), if yes then check the rendering mode of it.

Comment: did u get rid of these warnings somehow?

Comment: same here.
Any news!?

Answer (score 1):

I met with this warning, when I was programmatically selecting the `MKMarkerAnnotationView` in animated fashion.

I resolved my UI issues, by calling `prepareForDisplay` API on `MKMarkerAnnotationView`:

```swift
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    let view = mapView.view(for: annotation)
    view?.prepareForDisplay()
}
```

Let me know if this helps.

Best,
Boris

Comment: Looks like the message has nothing to do with annotations.
On my app, it shows up after a map.setRegion command, with or without annotations on the map.
And playing with the map, more similar messages appear.

Answer (score 1):

I thought about this warning for a long time, and after a while I found out what my problem was. When creating a map with the `MapKit` framework, the program returned this error depending on the values that were passed as `latitudeDelta` and `longitudeDelta` in `MKCoordinateSpan`. So, I just reduced these values, which brought the map closer, but the warnings stopped appearing. My working code is error-free:

```
import SwiftUI
import MapKit

struct MapView: View {
    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
    
    @State private var region = MKCoordinateRegion()
    
    var body: some View {
        Map(coordinateRegion: $region).onAppear() {
            setRegion(coordinate)
        }
    }
    
    private func setRegion(_ coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
        region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: coordinate, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.040, longitudeDelta: 0.040))
    }
}

struct MapView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        MapView1(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 55.7522200, longitude:  37.6155600))
    }

}
```

Before that, the values were as follows::
`region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: coordinate, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.1, longitudeDelta: 0.1))`

Answer (score -9):

I have the same problem with you in my MapView.

I just disable system log in my scheme, and my `MKPointAnnotation` also works.

> OS_ACTIVITY_MODE: disable

[image]

Comment: This disables the log, but is there a way to fix the issue ?

Comment: This flag also will stop constraint issues to appear in the console. So I don’t recommend using it.